OpenMP Performance Issue: Parallelism not improving execution time
I have this code;
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NUM_VERTICES 1024

int distance[NUM_VERTICES];
int shortestPathTree[NUM_VERTICES];
int predecessor[NUM_VERTICES];

int main(void) 
{
    int i;

    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(3)
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i) {
        distance[i] = INT_MAX;
        shortestPathTree[i] = 0;
        predecessor[i] = -1;
    }

    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    double iteration_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf("Execution time: %f seconds\n", iteration_time);

    return 0; 
}


’ve tried this version, which is the closest to the specifications. I’ve also experimented with changing the approach, using sections, and testing different scheduling strategies. The last thing I tried was adding print statements (as shown in the comments) to observe the behavior of each thread. However, I’ve noticed that when thread 2 starts, it processes iterations 30 onwards without allowing other threads to print, almost as if once it acquires the resources, it doesn't relinquish them.
I’ve been working on this for about three days now, trying different things, but nothing seems to work. I also find it frustrating that, after this, I’ll be implementing Dijkstra’s algorithm, where the optimal number of threads appears to be 5. It seems like the code can parallelize to some extent, but it’s not consistent for the other tasks.
Here are some of the results I’ve observed for different thread configurations:

1 thread and 2 threads: 0.000142 seconds

1 thread and 3 threads: 0.000129 seconds

1 thread and 4 threads: 0.000120 seconds


As we can see, the time tends to decrease with more threads initially, but there will eventually be a point where adding more threads will not yield further improvements.

1 thread and 5 threads: 0.000115 seconds

1 thread and 6 threads: 0.000121 seconds


So my pc seems able to paralize but not for the start point that is only best with 1 thread

Parallelizing, via OpenMP or otherwise, is not a magic "go faster" button.  Parallelization adds overhead, and the resulting concurrency only advantages the part that actually runs in parallel.

Additionally, your parallel loop does nothing but assignments, and none of the assigned values are ever used, so it's entirely possible that the whole loop is simply optimized out, leaving nothing but serial code.

1024 iterations of very simple code is likely to be dominated by the time spent creating omp threads.

@JohnBollinger All those variables are being used, this is a over simplified version of the code as i see it as two parts and is the upper part that is the initialization what is wrong

@user28302579, if you wanted to ask about a different program then you should have done that, instead.  But the matter of possibly optimizing the loop out is a side issue.  The main one is that you are doing very little work overall, and it's not surprising if parallelizing part of it as you've done does not produce enough performance benefit to offset the additional overhead involved.

@Shawn Yeah that is a thing im thinking about but due to being an example of something like this already is the specification I was like it must be there something that is slipping throw my fingers, thanks a lot

@JohnBollinger I wanted to send out the whole code but told me to just send the problem to be the minimal running code, now I cant post it in comments due to being too long for that, what should I do?

@user28302579, if you wanted to present different code then the correct thing to do would be to edit the question.  But I'm not seeing what's to be gained in this case.  If you see similar performance scaling from a program that does use the assigned values, then it's probably best simply to assume that that's not explained by the loop being optimized out.

@JohnBollinger True thanks a lot <3

Each array takes 4 KiB of RAM. Assuming data is stored in the RAM and not the CPU cache, a relatively recent mid-end machine should do that in less than 2 µs in sequential (e.g. 16 GiB/s DDR4 RAM). Thus, we can clearly conclude that >95% the observed timings are overheads. This includes : OpenMP runtime lazy initialization, thread creation+join, page faults.

Btw, a SIMD code with NT stores can certainly be faster than that. Not to mention setting memory in parallel can be detrimental for performance also due to NUMA effects (impact the timings of the rest of the code accessing data later). Thus, put it shortly: don't do that in parallel ;) .

The most valuable information is in the comments to your question. I will reply directly to the question: why you do not see improvement in an execution time with parallel loop.
Because the initialization and thread managing overhead overcomes the actual data processing. Try the below code. It is a slightly modified version of your code. You should see the effect.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NUM_VERTICES 1024 * 1024
#define N_THREADS_0    1
#define N_THREADS_1    4

int main(void) 
{
    int i;

    double start_time;
    double end_time;
    double iteration_time;
    int *distance;
    int *shortestPathTree;
    int *predecessor;

    distance         = malloc(NUM_VERTICES * sizeof(int));
    shortestPathTree = malloc(NUM_VERTICES * sizeof(int));
    predecessor      = malloc(NUM_VERTICES * sizeof(int));

    if((NULL == distance) || (NULL == shortestPathTree) || (NULL == predecessor)) {
        return 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i){
        distance[i]         = 0;
        shortestPathTree[i] = 0;
        predecessor[i]      = 0;
    }

    start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(N_THREADS_0)
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i) {
        distance[i]         = INT_MAX;
        shortestPathTree[i] = 0;
        predecessor[i]      = -1;
    }

    end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    iteration_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf(" 1* execution time: %f seconds\n", iteration_time);

    start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(N_THREADS_1)
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i) {
        distance[i]         = INT_MAX;
        shortestPathTree[i] = 0;
        predecessor[i]      = -1;
    }

    end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    iteration_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf(" 2* execution time: %f seconds\n", iteration_time);

    return 0; 
}


You should initialize the 3 arrays after the allocation and before the first loop, otherwise what you are timing in the first loop is also the "first touch" of the array elements, that is the effective allocation of memory pages (which is not negligible compared to a simple assignment).

Also, after each loop you should print one element of each array, to ensure that the compiler won't completely optimize out the loops.

@PierU good point about an assignment. I did an update. Bad point about printing. Better handle it with disabling optimizations.

OK, for illustration purpose, running the code without compiler optimizations can make some sense. But parallelizing is all about getting higher performances, and the first step to get high performances is to enable compiler optimization. Moreover, running without, then with optimizations, can illustrate that the minimum workload to observe a significant speedup when parallelizing is generally higher (or even much higher) with the compiler optimization turned on (because the OpenMP overheads are fixed and do not depend on the compiler optimizations for the most part).

@PierU I agree with your commitment to the topic ;) we might have taken the code in the answer to much higher level :) just.. please remember SO rules. one question - one answer.
